# How to create a new property on a react object? Error: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following class:

```
// @flow

import {
    ACTION_SHORTCUT_TRIGGERED,
    AUDIO_MUTE,
    createShortcutEvent,
    sendAnalytics
} from '../../analytics';
import { translate } from '../../base/i18n';
import { MEDIA_TYPE } from '../../base/media';
import { connect } from '../../base/redux';
import { AbstractAudioMuteButton } from '../../base/toolbox';
import type { AbstractButtonProps } from '../../base/toolbox';
import { isLocalTrackMuted } from '../../base/tracks';
import { muteLocal } from '../../remote-video-menu/actions';

declare var APP: Object;

type Props = AbstractButtonProps & {
    _audioMuted: boolean,
    _disabled: boolean,

    dispatch: Function,
    _audioStatusText: {
        writeable: true
    }
}

/**
 * Component that renders a toolbar button for toggling audio mute.
 *
 * @extends AbstractAudioMuteButton
 */
class AudioMuteButton extends AbstractAudioMuteButton<Props, *> {
    accessibilityLabel = 'toolbar.accessibilityLabel.mute';
    label = 'toolbar.mute';
    tooltip = 'toolbar.mute';

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        // Bind event handlers so they are only bound once per instance.
        this._onKeyboardShortcut = this._onKeyboardShortcut.bind(this);
    }

   
    /**
     * Indicates if audio is currently muted ot nor.
     *
     * @override
     * @protected
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    _isAudioMuted() {
        return this.props._audioMuted;
    }

    _updatedAudioStatusText(statustext) {
        return this.props._audioStatusText = statustext;
    }
    
    _onKeyboardShortcut: () => void;

        _onKeyboardShortcut() {
        sendAnalytics(
            createShortcutEvent(
                AUDIO_MUTE,
                ACTION_SHORTCUT_TRIGGERED,
                { enable: !this._isAudioMuted() }));

        super._handleClick();
    }


    _setAudioMuted(audioMuted: boolean) {
        this.props.dispatch(muteLocal(audioMuted));
        var statustext='';
        this.props._audioMuted ? statustext = "Unmute" : statustext ="Mute";
        this.props.dispatch(this._updatedAudioStatusText(statustext));

        console.log("test" )
        console.log(this.props._audioMuted)
        console.log(this.props._audioStatusText)
    }

    _isDisabled() {
        return this.props._disabled;
    }
}

/**
 * Maps (parts of) the redux state to the associated props for the
 * {@code AudioMuteButton} component.
 *
 * @param {Object} state - The Redux state.
 * @private
 * @returns {{
 *     _audioMuted: boolean,
 *     _disabled: boolean
 * }}
 */
function _mapStateToProps(state): Object {
    const _audioMuted = isLocalTrackMuted(state['features/base/tracks'], MEDIA_TYPE.AUDIO);
    const _disabled = state['features/base/config'].startSilent;
    const _audioStatusText = state._audioStatusText;

    return {
        _audioMuted,
        _disabled,
        _audioStatusText
    };
}

export default translate(connect(_mapStateToProps)(AudioMuteButton));
```

When I try to run the code, I'm getting the following error message

> UnhandledError: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
> property '_audioStatusText' of object '#'

It's failing on the line that tries to assign the value to the audioStatusText.

```
_updatedAudioStatusText(statustext) {
    return this.props._audioStatusText = statustext;
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to fix this error. I checked other similar posts and saw the suggestion to use the "writable" keyword... but it still fails.  I'm not a react / redux programmer so I'm just learning as I go along.  But I am trying to add logic to create a new property called "audioStatusText" that will adjust whenever the state of the Audio button changed.

Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

```
_updatedAudioStatusText() {
    if (this.props_audioMuted == true) {
       return "Unmute"
    } else {
        return "Mute"
    }
}

_setAudioMuted(audioMuted: boolean) {
    this.props.dispatch(muteLocal(audioMuted));
    this.props.dispatch(this._updatedAudioStatusText());
}
```

**EDIT 2**

So i"ve updated my code to look like this:

```
type Props = AbstractButtonProps & {
    _audioMuted: boolean,
    _disabled: boolean,
    dispatch: Function,
    _audioStatusText: String
}

_updatedAudioStatusText() {

    if (this.props_audioMuted == true) {
       return {
           type: AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT,
           text: "Unmute"
       }
    } else {

        return {
            type: AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT,
            text: "Mute"
        }
    }
}

_setAudioMuted(audioMuted: boolean) {
    this.props.dispatch(muteLocal(audioMuted));
    this.props.dispatch({_audioStatusText:this._updatedAudioStatusText()})
```

In the related actions.js file I have created the following:

```
export const AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT = 'AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT';

export function toggleAudioStatusText(text) {
    return { type: AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT, text }
}
```

Right now, the system fails with the error Uncaught ReferenceError: AUDIO_STATUS_TEXT is not defined Script

But I can see in the react debugger that I have a props for this button called _audioStatusText.  It's currently "undefined"

Comment: What do you want to achieve in ```_updatedAudioStatusText``` function ?

Comment: @Anup if the _audioMuted is true, then I want the _audioStatusText to say "Unmuted" and vice versa.

Comment: ```this.props.dispatch(this._updatedAudioStatusText(statustext))``` According to this line your ```_updatedAudioStatus```Text function should return a value to be dispatch i.e. in your case it should return either "UnMute" or "Mute"


Secondly when you dispatch any action and the component is connected to the store with ```mapSatetToProps``` you dont have to explicitly assign value to props. Rather the component will listen to the change from the redux store itself.

Comment: hm ok.  Can you take a look at edit 1?  to see if I've understood?

Comment: looks good to me and update your dispatch now from ```this.props.dispatch(this._updatedAudioStatusText(statustext))``` to 
```this.props.dispatch({_audioStatusText:this._updatedAudioStatusText(statustext)})```

Comment: @Anup I'm getting an error that statusText is not defined.  which ... I guess is true.  In the case of the dispatch method, we are passing in "statusText" as an argument.  but it's not created anywhere. I'll update question with Edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220452/discussion-between-dot-and-anup).

Answer (score 0):

React props are not directly changeable. They are read-only values that only can be read, not written. You are using redux already and if you need changeable values, there are 2 choices:

1. Use state for component-specific values.
2. Write reducer and action, and dispatch action so that it can change the value inside redux store.

Based on your current code, choice 2 is more eligible. As you already getting _audioStatusText from redux store, you need redux action and reducer to change the value.

Please refer this document on how to write redux actions and reducers.
https://reduxjs.org/basica/usage-with-react

I can also help you to finish this code, if you share some more files, specifically related to redux.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of redux and react.  I inherited this from someone.  What specifically do you need as far as redux?  I can provide. This actually an opensource project. https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/react/features/toolbox/components/web/Toolbox.js  The mic button the toolbox is what i'm trying to add text to.

Comment: I need to see how your redux store, actions and reducers are configured.

Comment: I tried to update my question - Edit 2 - to include the info you need.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes, things still need to be revised. You need to write reducer as well. And, actions should be fired through dispatch, they can't be run directly.

Comment: Can you post reducers and store files too?